# ASP.NET mvc anchor tag helper with two input parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

In my ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1 project, I need to pass two parameters - one for id and one for customerNumber. For passing id I know I can use `asp-route-id`. How do I do the same for customerNumber:

**Parts of View**:

```
....
@foreach (var item in Model.lstCustomers)
{
  <tr>
     <td><a asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerID">@item.CustomerName</a></td>
  </tr>
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same way you've done for ID

`asp-route-parameter` must match the parameter from the controller method

```
....
@foreach (var item in Model.lstCustomers)
{
  <tr>
     <td><a asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@item.CustomerID" asp-route-customerNumber="@item.customerNumber">@item.CustomerName</a></td>
  </tr>
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that `asp-route-parameter must match the parameter from the controller method`. That was a key point of your suggested solution.